# Combine a (m x n x p) matrix (image) of 8 bit numbers to a (m x n) matrix of 24 bit numbers and vice versa

Tags: matlab, binary

Say there is a matrix of (m x n x p), esp. a color image with R G and B channel. Each channel information is 8-bit integer.

But, for an analysis, the three 8-bit values have to be combined to get a 24-bit value and the analysis is done on the (m x n) matrix of 24-bit values.

After the analysis, the matrix has to be decomposed back to three 8-bit channels for displaying the results.

What I am doing right now:

- Iterating through all the values in the matrix
- Convert each decimal value to binary (using `dec2bin`)
- Combine the three binary values together to get a 24-bit number (using `strcat` and `bin2dec`)

Code:

`for i=1:m
        for j=1:n
            new_img(i,j) = bin2dec(strcat(...
                sprintf('%.8d',str2double(dec2bin(img(i,j,1)))), ...
                sprintf('%.8d',str2double(dec2bin(img(i,j,2)))), ...
                sprintf('%.8d',str2double(dec2bin(img(i,j,3))))));
        end
    end`

For the decomposition back to three 8-bits after analysis, the exact reverse process is done, still iterating through (m x n) values.

The problem is huge computation time.

I know that this is the not the correct way of doing this. Is there any matrix operation that I can do to achieve this so that the computation is done quickly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although I don't understand why you'd "combine" the rgb planes this way, this'll get you what you're looking for in one command.

```
a = bitshift(img(:,:,1),16)+...
     bitshift(img(:,:,2,8)+...
     img(:,:,3);
```

And to invert the process requires binary masking in addition to shifting back to the right.

```
A=zeros(size(img));
A(:,:,1)=bitshift(a,-16);
A(:,:,2)=bitshift(bitand(a,2^16-2^8),-8);
A(:,:,3)=bitand(a,2^8-2^0);
```

Comment: Hmm... should it be:

bitshift(img(:,:,1),16)+...
     bitshift(img(:,:,2),8)+...
     img(:,:,3);

instead?

Comment: It should, now you're adding three panes. Also you should use `squeeze` probably, to make it `mxn`, not `mxnx3`. All else considered this is the way to go.

Comment: good catch @davidleejy, thanks!  no need to squeeze, since it's adding 3 mxnx1 matrices matlab collapses the singleton dimension automatically.

Comment: Thanks for the support. That works! The reason why I am doing this is just to experiment with different ways of Image compression techniques. Also, it would be great if you can help with converting this back to three 8 bit values. This is required to plot the image after processing.

Comment: I hope this does the conversion back to 8-bits

`r_img = zeros(size(img1));
r_img(:,:,1) = new_img ./ 2^16;
r_img(:,:,2) = new_img ./ 2^8;
r_img(:,:,3) = new_img ;`